# Run function whenever var is defined

Tags: javascript, eval, user-input, user-defined-functions

I am working on a project with a lot of user-generated code(inspired by this video http://vimeo.com/36579366).  What I want to do is to eval() a chunk of user-input code, and run a function every time a var is defined, or 2 variables are multiplied, or some other action occurs.

Is there a way to do this in JS?

Obviously, I could search the field for "var ..." and then read what comes next, and then do whatever I need to do with that information, but, for a number of reasons, I would rather do it "legitimately" where I actually react to something being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Intercession API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in certain versions of Javascript (also known as proxies). From this you can redefine what happens when objects mutate by writing your own code.

If that's not possible, but you know the names of the variables in advance, you can use [setters, getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters), or a polyfill for [Object.watch](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) to achieve the same effect.

If you don't know what the variable names are going to be, I recommend running the user-defined Javascript through a parser like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) to obtain an AST. From this you can inject arbitrary syntax directly into the AST when you see variables being defined (or hoisted), and then compile back to working code. You'll be looking for JSON objects with `"type": "VariableDeclaration"`.

Comment: Esprima looks promising. Thanks!